# Passing data to a chart javascript object and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, charts, chart.js

What is the best approach to display the data in a chart?
To begin, my application has an empty array that receives objects.

```
// location where the users are storage
let usersList = [];
// these are the information from an user
const newUser = {
        name:`${user.name.first} ${user.name.last}`,
        social: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 )
}
```

So, by the end of my code, I have the chart, everything is working but with dummy data.

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],      // should get the usersList.name
        datasets: [{
            label: ' Views per channel ',
            data: [12, 10, 3, 5, 2, 3],                                     // // should get the usersList.social
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Ideally, I would need to change the labels to have the name of each user, and the data to have the social of each user. My initial thought was a for loop, but I remember that ES6 has array destructuring.
I am not sure how to approach the problem, do you have any insight?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the `usersList` to create the arrays that contain the desired attributes of the users.

Your code would have to be changed as follows:

```
data: {
  labels: usersList.map(u => u.name),
  datasets: [{
    label: ' Views per channel ',
    data: usersList.map(u => u.social),
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
}
```